# How to retrieve FASTA sequences according to coordinate information using Python?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, regular-language, fasta

I would like to obtain the sequences according to the bed file B.bed which contain coordinates information of sequences by matching the coordinates to the fasta file which is A.fasta and retrieve the corresponding sequences according to B.bed file. Fasta file is normal file with sequence ID and followed by its nucleotides ATCG. But I get the key error below. Can anyone help me?

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
from collections import defaultdict

# read names and postions from bed file
positions = defaultdict(list)
with open('B.bed') as f:
    for line in f:
        name, start, stop = line.split()
        positions[name].append((int(start), int(stop)))

# parse faste file and turn into dictionary
records = SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse(open('A.fasta'), 'fasta'))

# search for short sequences
short_seq_records = []
for name in positions:
    for (start, stop) in positions[name]:        
        long_seq_record = records[name]
        long_seq = long_seq_record.seq
        alphabet = long_seq.alphabet
        short_seq = str(long_seq)[start-1:stop]        
        short_seq_record =SeqRecord(Seq(name))+ '\t'+str(start)+'\t'+str(stop)+'\t' + SeqRecord(Seq(short_seq, alphabet))
    short_seq_records.append(short_seq_record)

# write to file
with open('C.fasta', 'w') as f:
    SeqIO.write(short_seq_records,f, 'fasta')
```

**A.fasta**

```
>chr16:13361561-13361573
TAGTGGGTCAGAC
>chr6_apd_hap1:2165669-2165681
AGATGAGTCATCA
>chr10:112612173-112612185
AAGTGTGTCAGCT
```

**B.bed**

```
chr6_apd_hap1   2165668 2165681
chr10   112612172   112612185
```

**Expected output for C.fasta**

```
>chr6_apd_hap1:2165669-2165681
AGATGAGTCATCA
>chr10:112612173-112612185
AAGTGTGTCAGCT
```

But I received error below:

```
long_seq_record = records[name]
KeyError: 'chr6_apd_hap1'
```

Comment: Have you checked what's actually in `records`, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `positions` is a `defaultdict` which has as keys the names from the BED file:

```
>>> print positions.keys()
['chr10', 'chr6_apd_hap1']
```

And `records` is a dictionary which has as keys the headers of the FASTA file, minus the `>` at the beginning, but they still include the colon and the position on the chromosome:

```
>>> print records.keys()
['chr16:13361561-13361573', 'chr6_apd_hap1:2165669-2165681', 'chr10:112612173-112612185']
```

So you first need to transform your `records` keys to loose the extra info so that you can use the `positions` keys to retrieve them. You can do this by adding the following line after you've created the `records` dictionary:

```
records = {key.split(':')[0]: value for (key, value) in records.iteritems()}
```

Also, the way you're currently constructing your `short_seq_record` doesn't really work. Replace the lines

```
short_seq = str(long_seq)[start-1:stop]        
short_seq_record =SeqRecord(Seq(name))+ '\t'+str(start)+'\t'+str(stop)+'\t' + SeqRecord(Seq(short_seq, alphabet))
```

with:

```
short_seq = Seq(str(long_seq)[start-1:stop], alphabet)
short_seq_id = '{0}\t{1}\t{2}'.format(name, start, stop)
short_seq_record = SeqRecord(short_seq, id=short_seq_id, description='')
```

Comment: According to your suggestion I have made changes to the code and I got this in my C.fasta>chr10 112612172 112612185 <unknown description>
>chr6_apd_hap1 2165668 2165681 <unknown description>

Comment: Well, if you want a description, add a description when you create the `SeqRecord` or set it to an empty string if you don't want it. I've updated my code, but be sure to also read the [documentation](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SeqRecord.SeqRecord-class.html)

Comment: The nucleotides are not found in the file. Only the sequence header.

Comment: That is indeed the case with your sample files. But that makes sense. The sequences in your sample `A.fasta` are only 13 nucleotides long. Later on you search for the short sequences based on the positions found in the BED file (eg. from position 112612172 to 112612185 for chr10). Since these positions are way bigger than the length of your sample sequences, they indeed return no nucleotides found. But, if you replace your sample `A.fasta` with a real-world FASTA file with long sequences, you will get back a result with the desired sequences.

Comment: still I can't get the nucleotides even though I use larger fasta file

Comment: Do you get an error? How long are your sequences? What have you tried to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: Yes I did. I tried with 2000bp upstream and downstream.  My output is still without the nucleotides it only return sequence header.